# Result for a Select query returns values without Slash

Tags: sql, oracle, vbscript, asp-classic

I have an Oracle database and I run a query in SQL developer as

```sql
select C_VALUE from master where SECTION='val1' and KEY='val2'
```

The result I get is as follows:

```
E:\folder1\file1
```

That query returns me a folder path as above.

Now the actual problem is that whenever I run a query from my VBScript ASP project, the value I get is as follows:

```
E:folder1file1
```

If you notice there are no slash ().
I do not know why this is happening.
The query I am running from my VBScript code is as follows:

```vb
strSQL = ""
strSQL = strSQL & "SELECT C_VALUE" 
strSQL = strSQL & " AS SelectedCol" 
strSQL = strSQL & " FROM MASTER" 
strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE SECTION = 'val1'"
strSQL = strSQL & " AND KEY='val2'" 
set objRs = objDb.CreateDynaset(strSQL, 4) 
result = objRs("SelectedCol")
```

Here the value of `result` is obtained as `E:folder1file1` without the slashes.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Can you show us sample table data?

Comment: @Lankymart . Yes. I did it now. Sorry, I thought upvoting the answer meant 'accepting' the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Raxak no apology required, it's a common misconception. You can actually up-vote and accept an answer. An up-vote is a visual indicator that you agree with the solution and the accepted flag is a visual indicator to everyone that the accepted answer solved your problem. Anyone can vote only the OP can accept.

Comment: @Raxak This also applies to questions you answer yourself, it's perfectly acceptable to accept your own answer if that's what solved your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this happens is because in Oracle backslash `\` is used as an [Escape Character](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28304/cqspcl.htm#CCREF2091). This means instead of just being output it has special meaning *(the character immediately following the backslash is escaped)* and afterwards is discarded.

You can ignore Escape characters by escaping them *(`\\`)* like so;

```
SELECT REPLACE(C_VALUE, '\', '\\') AS SelectedCol
FROM MASTER 
WHERE SECTION='val1' AND KEY='val2'
```

---

While you could [use `RELACE()` to substitute the backslash for another character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40988573/692942) this then requires another step in the code to replace the substituted character with backslash again. Which seems pointless when the SQL can handle it for you with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

### You can try this

First change your script

`select REPLACE (C_VALUE, '\', '#')  from master where SECTION='val1' and KEY='val2'`

Then you can REPLACE again # to \ in vb

Comment: Ok, this is a workaround. Any reason as to the cause behind this problem? Why does my vbscript return without slashes? is there any special reason behind it?